# Unable to Reorder Rows within a Group using Row Drag in ag-Grid Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop, grid, ag-grid

I’m using ag-Grid with Angular and I’ve encountered an issue with reordering rows within a group using the row drag feature.

Here’s a snippet of my code: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ag-grid-packages-28pdxd?file=%2Fapp.component.ts%3A43%2C35)

With this setup, I expected to be able to reorder rows within a group by dragging and dropping them. However, the rows are not moving as expected.

I’ve read the ag-Grid documentation and tried various solutions, but none of them seem to work. I’m not sure if I’m missing something or if there’s a bug in ag-Grid.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your row data has a unique identifier that can be used to identify each row. You can use the id field for this purpose.

**Configure Ag grid**

In your AG-Grid configuration, set the getRowId property to the name of the unique identifier (in this case, 'id').

```
<ag-grid-angular [getRowId]="getRowId"></ag-grid-angular>

getRowId(params: GetRowIdParams) {
    return params.data.id;
}

onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
   this.gridApi = params.api;

    // add id to each item, needed for immutable store to work
    immutableStore.forEach(function (data, index) {
       data.id = index;
    });
    params.api.setGridOption("rowData", immutableStore);
}
```

**Implement Row Drag and Drop:**
Use an immutable store as describe in ag grid documentation

```
onRowDragMove(event: RowDragEndEvent) {
        var movingNode = event.node;
        var overNode = event.overNode;
        var rowNeedsToMove = movingNode !== overNode;
        if (rowNeedsToMove) {
          // the list of rows we have is data, not row nodes, so extract the data
          var movingData = movingNode.data;
          var overData = overNode!.data;
          var fromIndex = immutableStore.indexOf(movingData);
          var toIndex = immutableStore.indexOf(overData);
          var newStore = immutableStore.slice();
          moveInArray(newStore, fromIndex, toIndex);
          immutableStore = newStore;
          this.gridApi.setGridOption("rowData", newStore);
          this.gridApi.clearFocusedCell();
        }
        function moveInArray(arr: any[], fromIndex: number, toIndex: number) {
          var element = arr[fromIndex];
          arr.splice(fromIndex, 1);
          arr.splice(toIndex, 0, element);
        }
    }
```

**To finish initialize the value of immutableStore:**

```
export class AppComponent {
// ...
}
var immutableStore: any[] = getData();
```

Answer (score -1):

I would go throw your code later, but i think u have some missed events
you can go either with removing the group and add rowDragManaged to true
as follow :

```
<ag-grid-angular
style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
[columnDefs]="columnDefs"
[defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
[groupDefaultExpanded]="groupDefaultExpanded"
[rowData]="rowData"
[class]="themeClass"
[rowDragManaged]="true" --> add this
(rowDragMove)="onRowDragMove($event)"
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
```

> 

```
  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
{ field: "athlete", rowDrag: rowDrag },
{ field: "country" }, ->> remove group here
{ field: "year", width: 100 },
{ field: "date" },
{ field: "sport" },
{ field: "gold" },
{ field: "silver" },
{ field: "bronze" },
];
```

or you can add your group but you need to implement drag and drop function

```
<ag-grid-angular
style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
[columnDefs]="columnDefs"
[defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
[groupDefaultExpanded]="groupDefaultExpanded"
[rowData]="rowData"
[class]="themeClass"
(rowDragMove)="onRowDragMove($event)"
[rowDragManaged]="false" --> here
(rowDragEnter)="onRowDragEnter($event)" --> here
(rowDragLeave)="onRowDragLeave($event)" --> here
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" ></ag-grid-angular
```

> 

```
draggedNode: any

onRowDragEnter(event: RowDragEnterEvent){
 draggedNode = event
}
onRowDragLeave(event: RowDragEndEvent){
  // TODO: splice the node and move it to it's new index
  // ex:array.splice(index,0, array.splice(this.draggedElement.index, 1) [0]);
}
```